# PEAR/Pyrus installation

Tags: php, pear, pyrus

I am installing Pyrus on my CentOS server by using the following command:

`$ php pyrus.phar install PEAR2_Pyrus`

I am getting an error:

**The sqlite3 extension is required.
You must compile PHP with sqlite3 enabled, or install the necessary extension for your distribution.**

Since the PHP 5.3 was installed by [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) control panel itself, I am not sure how to install Pyrus now. Please help!

1. What is `sqlite3` extension?
2. How to install it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. `sqlite3` might be already installed on your system.
 You can enable it by adding this line to the end of your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

The file `php_sqlite3.dll` should be in the `/ext` directory if it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. SQLite is an embedded database, as described on http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite.php
2. No idea. Ask the plesk support or search the web: http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f16/i-want-install-php-5-my-plesk-server-how-can-i-do-correctly-996/